# Древнерусский язык. Повесть временных лет

Tags: фонетика, историческая-грамматика

1)Скажите, пожалуйста, как читается слово "времяньных" из полного названия ПВЛ: "Се повести времяньных лет, откуду есть пошла Русская земля, кто в Киеве нача первее княжити и откуду Русская земля стала есть"?

2) Как правильно читаются буквы "ь" и "ъ" в древнерусском тексте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/ъ/ — фонема заднего ряда среднего подъема, т. е. как и /о/. Произносится она как краткий [о], ср. гласный в первом слоге слова *пр**а**родитель*.

/ь/ — фонема переднего ряда среднего подъема, т. е. как, например, /е/. Произносится как краткий [е] (['э]), ср. гласный в первом слоге и на конце слова *пр**и**ближени**е***.

Мы не можем сказать, как именно читался какой-либо текст на древнерусском языке. Вы можете пытаться произносить сочетание *ньн* как [н'ьн], но и прочтение [нн] едва ли будет ошибочным — в конце концов, вы же не общаться собрались, а лишь хотите прочитать отрывок древней летописи.